# What are the qualification criteria for the world team championship?

Tags: world-championship, tournament

The world team chess championship concluded recently and Russia won the Gold. But there were only ten countries that participated in the event. What are the criteria followed to select the countries participating in this event?

Answer (score 3):

From the [FIDE Handbook](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=102&view=article):

> 1.4.1 Teams 
>    Qualification for the FIDE World Team Championship according to the following criteria:
>    a.The previous event's World Chess Team Champion 
>    b.The three highest-placed teams in the FIDE Olympiad prior to the event.
>    c.The four Continental Champions. The qualifiers will be the winners of the ultimate, respective Continental Championship organised at least six months prior to the World Team Championship.
>    d.A team from the organizing federation.
>    e.A team to be nominated by FIDE President.
>
> If any team would have already qualified according to one of these criteria, this place will be given to the next highest ranked country, in the Olympiad preceding the World Team Championship.